# Filter on an Attribute (XPath-LINQ to XML) by using parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, linq-to-xml

1. This code is not work

   ```
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(string par)
   {
       String JsonData, JsonFromXML;
       XElement root = XElement.Load("http://www.mywebsite.com/mapdata_xml.xml");
       IEnumerable<XElement> address =
           from el in root.Elements("marker")
           where (string) el.Attribute("province") == par
           orderby (string)el.Attribute("name")
           select el;


       var XMLData = "";
       foreach (XElement el in address)
           XMLData = XMLData + el;
       //XMLData = "<markers>" + XMLData + "</markers>";


       XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
       xd.LoadXml("<markers>" + XMLData + "</markers>");

       JsonFromXML = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xd);

       JsonFromXML = JsonFromXML.Remove(0, 11);
       JsonFromXML = JsonFromXML.Substring(0, JsonFromXML.Length - 1);
       JsonData = JsonFromXML.Replace("\"@", "\"");

       return new HttpResponseMessage()
       {
           Content = new StringContent(JsonData)
       };
   }
   ```

Web API : http://localhost:55607/api/Test?par=%22Pursat%22

Parameter: par

Question: I have a Web API (http://localhost:55607/api/Test?par=%22Pursat%22). I want to pass parameter "Pursat" to ASP.Net (public HttpResponseMessage Get(string par) name "Par"). Then I get nothing. However, when I use like this (where (string) el.Attribute("province") == "Pursat"), I can get data from my code.

2. This code work well

   ```
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(string par)
   {
       String JsonData, JsonFromXML;
       XElement root = XElement.Load("http://www.mywebsite.com/mapdata_xml.xml");
       IEnumerable<XElement> address =
           from el in root.Elements("marker")
           where (string) el.Attribute("province") == "Pursat"
           orderby (string)el.Attribute("name")
           select el;


       var XMLData = "";
       foreach (XElement el in address)
           XMLData = XMLData + el;
       //XMLData = "<markers>" + XMLData + "</markers>";


       XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
       xd.LoadXml("<markers>" + XMLData + "</markers>");

       JsonFromXML = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xd);

       JsonFromXML = JsonFromXML.Remove(0, 11);
       JsonFromXML = JsonFromXML.Substring(0, JsonFromXML.Length - 1);
       JsonData = JsonFromXML.Replace("\"@", "\"");

       return new HttpResponseMessage()
       {
           Content = new StringContent(JsonData)
       };
   }
   ```

I want to query data by using parameter "par" instead fixed data "Pursat".

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the value in with double quotes (%22 = " in HTML Encoding).   So in reality, what's happening is that the where in your query looks like this:

```
where (string) el.Attribute("province") == ""Pursat""
```

Whereas if you called it like this:

```
http://localhost:55607/api/Test?par=Pursat
```

your where clause would look like this:

```
where (string) el.Attribute("province") == "Pursat"
```